# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS wireless network not working

Tags: 14.04, networking

I have windows 10 on my Laptop and I install Ubuntu 14.04. Wifi works in windows but it doesn't work on Ubuntu and the "Enable Wireless" option is also missing.

I tried the command **lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net** and got the following output:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:0042] (rev 30)
Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:4035]
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07)
Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:381f]
Kernel driver in use: r8169
```

here are the results of the commands:
`modinfo ath10k_pci | grep 0042` :gives nothing 
 `sudo modprobe ath10k_pci && dmesg | grep ath`:

```
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:686 kmod_config_parse: 
/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf line 1: ignoring bad line starting 
with '11n_disable=1'
[   18.616258] audit: type=1400 audit(1521715330.062:12): 
apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" 
name="/usr/lib/telepathy/mission-control-5" pid=884 
comm="apparmor_parser"
[   18.616273] audit: type=1400 audit(1521715330.062:13): 
apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" 
name="/usr/lib/telepathy/telepathy-*" pid=884 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   18.616293] audit: type=1400 audit(1521715330.062:16): 
apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" 
name="/usr/lib/telepathy/telepathy-ofono" pid=884 
comm="apparmor_parser"
```

Comment: Do you have hardware switch to disable wlan?

Comment: No, I don't have a hardware switch

Comment: Please edit your question to add the rsult of these terminal commands: `modinfo ath10k_pci | grep 0042` and also: `sudo modprobe ath10k_pci && dmesg | grep ath`

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu forums is discussion about that. You can see the whole thread here: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2305201